# Visually disable flat button ( <input type="button"> ) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have 2 buttons , one is the normal <button> and another is flat button using <input>. I want to disable the buttons for 5 sec after every click. The disabled function works fine but in the flat-button, How can i make it visually 'disabled' , like being dimmed or frozen and also disable hover.

```js
function enable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function disable(id) {
    alert(id+" is disabled for 5 seconds.")
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        enable(id);
    }, 5000);

}
```

```css
#buttonflat {
    border: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: red;
}

#buttonflat:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>DISABLE FLAT BUTTON</h1>
    <br>
    <button id="button" onClick=disable(id)> GOL_101_019_010 </button>
    <br><br>    
    <input id="buttonflat" type="button" value="GOL_101_019_010" onClick="disable(id)" />
    <br><br>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `<input type="button">`: it's an inflexible anachronism from the days of HTML4. Use `<button type="button">` (or `<button type="submit">`) instead.

Comment: ... "While `<input>` elements of type button are still perfectly valid HTML, the newer `<button>` element is now the favored way to create buttons. Given that a `<button>`’s label text is inserted between the opening and closing tags, you can include HTML in the label, even images." [input type button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the brightness using `filter` and simulate like it is `disabled`. Change brightness accordingly

```
filter: brightness(80%);
```

```js
function enable(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function disable(id) {
  alert(id + " is disabled for 5 seconds.")
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    enable(id);
  }, 5000);

}
```

```css
#buttonflat {
  border: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: red;
}

#buttonflat:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#buttonflat:disabled {
  user-select: none;
  filter: brightness(80%);
}
```

```html
<h1>DISABLE FLAT BUTTON</h1>
<br>
<button id="button" onClick=disable(id)> GOL_101_019_010 </button>
<br><br>
<input id="buttonflat" type="button" value="GOL_101_019_010" onClick="disable(id)" />
<br><br>
```

You can also change `background-color` to `lightblue` and `color` to `red` like you can't hover it.

You can also change the cursor

```
cursor: not-allowed;
```

```js
function enable(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function disable(id) {
  alert(id + " is disabled for 5 seconds.")
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    enable(id);
  }, 5000);

}
```

```css
#buttonflat {
  border: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: red;
}

#buttonflat:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#buttonflat:disabled {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: red;
  user-select: none;
  filter: brightness(80%);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<h1>DISABLE FLAT BUTTON</h1>
<br>
<button id="button" onClick=disable(id)> GOL_101_019_010 </button>
<br><br>
<input id="buttonflat" type="button" value="GOL_101_019_010" onClick="disable(id)" />
<br><br>
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer (sorry!) because not only does it depend on browser support for `filter: brightness`, but it offers no alternatives for visually-impaired users or non-browser-based engines. Whenever you're doing anything with custom form controls and directly-user-interactive elements you should also include `aria` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS opacity feature, as well as the pointerEvents feature in your disable/enable methods:

```
function enable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = "auto"; 
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1"
}

function disable(id) {
    alert(id+" is disabled for 5 seconds.")
    document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = "none"; 
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = ".5"
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        enable(id);
    }, 5000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to perhaps style the `disabled` attrbute. E.g,:

```css
[disabled]{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Will make the opacity of any element with the `disabled` attribute have an opacity of `0.5`.

```js
function enable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function disable(id) {
    alert(id+" is disabled for 5 seconds.")
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        enable(id);
    }, 5000);

}
```

```css
#buttonflat {
    border: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: red;
}

#buttonflat:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

[disabled]{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>DISABLE FLAT BUTTON</h1>
    <br>
    <button id="button" onClick=disable(id)> GOL_101_019_010 </button>
    <br><br>    
    <input id="buttonflat" type="button" value="GOL_101_019_010" onClick="disable(id)" />
    <br><br>
</body>

</html>
```